# QGIS 2.16 Nødebo installation package for OSX

Tags: qgis

Im using qgis on my mac, few days ago the notification of the new available 2.16 version appeared in user interface. I went to the official webpage of the qgis but did not succeed. qgis.org is redirecting you to the kyngchaos for download http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis but there is still  only old 2.14 version for download.

Does anyone knows when it will be eventually available? or maybe someone can suggest where can i get fresh dmg.

Comment: Kyngchaos is on it! He has just released GDAL 2.1.

Comment: Now it's out! http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Answer (score 6):

Some people uses QGIS 2.8.x others the versions 2.10.x, 2.12.x and 2.14.x and some want to use the new version 2.16.x. Unfortunately, it is not yet available for Mac OS X and you have some solutions...

- Wait for William Kyngesburye version ( [Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/))
- Wait for [Homebrew Mac OSGeo version](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac)
- Compile yourself QGIS (Mac OS X is an Unix System and you have all the tools to compile)
- Download and use one of the Nightly Mac Build of QGIS from 'master' Branch (diary) from Larry Shaffer [Dakota Cartography](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/) (2.17 now)

Be patient because there are many differences between the 2.14 and 2.16 versions and there is not many people to propose versions for Mac OS X.

Comment: What do you mean with "not many people to propose versions for Mac OS X"? Propose as in create a package for everyone?

Comment: Only William Kyngesburye (native), Larry Shaffer (native and Homebrew)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install it using the MacPorts package manager.

Basically, all you have to do is install the latest MacPorts installer from https://www.macports.org/.

Then, on a terminal window, update your ports tree (i.e. list of packages) :

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

Now, check all the dependencies that QGIS needs:

```
port deps qgis
```

Last, you can install it:

```
sudo port install qgis
```

Note that, since many packages will be compiled from source, this process can take a long time - perhaps a couple of hours.

Once it finishes, you call invoke QGIS either by typing `qgis` on a terminal window, or browsing `Applications - MacPorts - QGIS`.

That will do it. Hope this is useful.